# passing two value for QueryString in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I use Livewire and put a filter for the table.
And my component has the following code:

```
    use WithPagination;
    public bool $loadData = false;
    public $filter_type = null;
    protected $queryString = ['filter_type'];
    

    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->filter_status = $type;
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
            $transactions = Transaction::when($this->filter_type, function ($query){
                    $query->where('type' , $this->filter_type);
                })
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();
          return view('livewire.backend.financial.transactions')->with('transactions' , collect($transactions)->paginate(10));
    }
```

When I apply a filter. The site address is as follows

```
https://example.com/table?filter_type=0
```

Now I want to give `filter_type‍‍` two values ​​(for example 0 and 1)
That is, show me items whose type is 0 and 1.
How do I do this?

Comment: I think you have another issue as well:  you're setting a different field in your setType function than the field you use in the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few scenarios you might want to cater for.

**1. Single value**

```
?filter_type=1
```

Return just the records where the `type` is equal to `1`. The value of `filter_type` will be a string `"1"`.

**2. Multiple values (or)**

```
?filter_type=1,2
```

Return all records where the `type` is equal to `1` or `2`. The value of `filter_type` will be a string `"1,2"`. You can split the string by the comma to obtain the actual desired values.

```
$values = explode(',', $filter_type);
```

**3. Multiple values (and)**

```
?filter_type[]=1&filter_type[]=2
```

Return all records where the `type` is `1` and `2` (doesn't make sense in this scenario but you get the idea). The value of `filter_type` will be an array `[0 => 1, 1 => 2]`.

The above are just suggestions, but lets pretend you go with `option 2`. You might implement it something along the lines of;

```
public function render()
{
    $types = explode(',', $this->filter_type);

    $transactions = Transaction::when($this->filter_type, function ($query) use ($types) {
        $query->whereIn('type', $types);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();

    // do what you want with the $transactions
}
```